# Will GCP Support Mysql 5.7 beyond October 2023?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I believe support for MySQL 5.7 is being withdrawn from Oct 2023. Does this mean GCP will remove my SQL Instance or force me to upgrade to MySQL 8, or will everything keep running?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/db-versions#major_version_deprecation_plan

Answer (score 0):

In a short answer: Folks from this place can not tell. Asking service provider should provide a more reliable answer. Generally, when service provider decides to discontinue a certain product, new users won't be able to purchase the said product when the time comes. However, as a courtesy, they may let existing subscribers continue with the use of product should the customers decide to **renew** the service.
The circumstances may be subject to some limitations e.g no longer be able to adjust resource allocated such as CPU or RAM capacity.